# How to remove the download icon in ionic?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic5

How to remove or change this icon in ionic4?

[image]

The icon that appears when the application loads

[image]

I know how to put inonka and background, but nowhere can I find a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add in your `config.xml` file

```
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false"/>
```